# default tab in windows 10 file explorer

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to have file explorer default to the view tab instead of the home tab. I never use a tab other than the view tab and so would like to avoid switching to it everytime.

Comment: Tech Junkie may have an answer for you "How to Configure Windows 10 File Explorer to Open with This PC View" https://www.techjunkie.com/configure-windows-10-file-explorer-this-pc-view/

Comment: The article shows the Quick Access / This PC view that I referred to in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can open Windows 10 File Explorer to Quick Access or This PC. View Tab, Options.  But you cannot open it just to the View tab. Office Applications with the Ribbon and Explorer with the Ribbon only open to Home.